# How to fix 'bundle.js 404 (not found)' after deploying to Heroku w/ an Express/Webpack/React app?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, webpack, deployment

In my console for my app I get

```
GET ...herokuapp.com/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Not sure what's wrong. 
This works fine on localhost. 
Can anyone help? :(

(This isn't built with the create-react-app)

Maybe I'm missing something that I should add to my script in package.json or maybe my file paths aren't correct?

I've tried to check the file paths but I'm very confused as to what the issue could be.

heroku log:

```
2019-01-31T02:13:39.026139+00:00 app[web.1]: > Glacial@1.0.0 start /app
2019-01-31T02:13:39.026141+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build && node ./backend/server.js
2019-01-31T02:13:39.026143+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-31T02:13:39.415395+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-31T02:13:39.415438+00:00 app[web.1]: > Glacial@1.0.0 build /app
2019-01-31T02:13:39.415441+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack --mode production
2019-01-31T02:13:39.415442+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-01-31T02:13:39.534502+00:00 app[web.1]: One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
2019-01-31T02:13:39.534507+00:00 app[web.1]: - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
2019-01-31T02:13:39.534510+00:00 app[web.1]: The original webpack full-featured CLI.
2019-01-31T02:13:39.536465+00:00 app[web.1]: We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
2019-01-31T02:13:40.938532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/bundle.js" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=392 protocol=https
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./backend/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
//Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Files
const expressMiddleware = require('./middleware/index.js');

//Middleware
expressMiddleware(app);

// Frontend Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/index.html'));
});

//Server
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server running on localhost 3000!'));

//Export App
module.exports = app;
```

middleware for server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const expressMiddleware = (app) => {
    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyparser.json());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/public')));
}

module.exports = expressMiddleware;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./frontend/app.jsx",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'/frontend/public'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/preset-react']
        }
      },
       {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
  },
  watch: true
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

File Structure Image
[image]

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom for front end routing?

Comment: No, I don't have any routes at the moment. Just trying to get hello world to appear in production.